# File upload/download failing

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on a website where I need to have upload/download functionality. Upload works fine, but when I press Download Uploaded File nearly nothing happens.

```
//Upload
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            fileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Files/" + filename));
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into FilesTable(FileName,FilePath) values(@Name,@Path)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", filename);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Path", "Files/" + filename);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            BindGridviewData();
        }
//Download
 protected void gvDetails_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select FileName,FilePath from FilesTable where Id=@Id", con);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", gvDetails.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
            SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;

                Response.ContentType = dr["type"].ToString();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dr["Name"].ToString());
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["data"]);
                Response.End();
            }
}
```

Comment: Have you try [Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sc65sadd.aspx) with a break-point ??

Comment: And what exactly does "nearly nothing" mean?

Comment: @ŽeniaBogdasic: Why don't you?

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: @radium I think it just refreshes the page.
huMptyduMpty I have only ran Code analysis.

Comment: @rahuldwivedi No, It doesn't show any errors/exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with your code:

1. Your `select` query only returns *FileName* and *FilePath* but you also try to retrieve *type* and *data* from database. You can add an extra column in table to store file type since your code already saves uploaded file in *Files* folder then you can use `dr["type"]`
2. You need to use *same file path* for downloading as well that you used for saving, either store absolute path or relative path in database:

   ```
   // Uploading
   string filePath = Server.MapPath("Files/" + filename); // Absolute path
   or 
   string filePath = "Files/" + filename; // Relative path
   ...
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Path", filePath);

   // Downloading
   string filePath = dr["FilePath"]; // Absolute path
   or
   string filePath = Server.MapPath(dr["FilePath"]); // Relative path
   ```
3. If file gets saved in folder instead of database then read its contents as *bytes* for sending to client using `File` or `FileStream` etc:

   ```
   // ReadAllBytes throws memory exception for large files
   byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
   ```
4. The `select` list contains *FileName* as column name and not just *Name*, replace `dr["Name"]` with `dr["FileName"]`